# How to lazy load for children in React Next JS?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I want to know how to lazy load for the children component in React Next JS.
Please see the below code from layout.tsx file which is from Next JS:

```
import {lazy, Suspense} from "react";
import "./globals.css";
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import Navbar from "./layouts/navbar";
import Footer from "./layouts/footer";
import Loading from "./loading/loading";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "ID",
  description: "Create your own ID!",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" sizes="any" />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/favicon.ico" sizes="any" />
      </head>
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <Navbar />
        <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>{children}</Suspense>
        <Footer />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

As you can see in the above code, I imported lazy and Suspense.
I also have a loading component that will be used in fallback.
I know how to use lazy by importing the component and also there is [dynamic](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/lazy-loading) in Next js that acts the same as lazy.
But what I want to do is to use lazy load for children and I don't know how to use lazy() function for the children and I never tried like that before.
TBH, not even sure if it is possible or not to do so.
Please kindly help me solve this problem and much appreciate your answers and any suggestions.

Thank You!!!

Answer (score -2):

In React, you can use the React.lazy() function to dynamically load components when they are needed. However, when using Next.js with server-side rendering (SSR), there are some considerations to take into account. Next.js has its own way of code splitting and dynamic imports that might not work directly with React.lazy().

In your case, you want to lazy load the children component in your RootLayout. You can achieve this by using Next.js's dynamic function with import() to dynamically load the children component. Here's how you can do it:

```
import { Suspense } from "react";
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'; // Import the dynamic function
import Loading from "./loading/loading";

const Navbar = dynamic(() => import("./layouts/navbar")); // Lazy load Navbar
const Footer = dynamic(() => import("./layouts/footer")); // Lazy load Footer

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" sizes="any" />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/favicon.ico" sizes="any" />
      </head>
      <body>
        <Navbar />
        <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
          {children}
        </Suspense>
        <Footer />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

In the code above, we've used the dynamic function from Next.js to dynamically import the Navbar and Footer components. Next.js will automatically split the code for these components and load them lazily.

However, note that in your RootLayout, you don't need to use React.lazy() or Suspense for the children component because Next.js handles code splitting and lazy loading for you automatically. You only need to wrap the children component in a Suspense when using React.lazy() for components that you are importing dynamically inside your children component.

Comment: Thanks for the answer bro @Rajat Saraswat but I don't get your answer because what I want to lazy load is the children component (Not Navbar and Footer). According to your example code, I don't think it will work but let me try first whether it works or not!